# Node-oidc-provider, how i can validate my acess token which already in jwt token

Tags: node.js, nestjs, auth0, node-oidc-provider

I use nestjs, and use node-oidc-provider package to make and identity provider, but currently stack to validate the jwt in my strategy middleware, which i follow from this tutorial

https://auth0.com/blog/developing-a-secure-api-with-nestjs-adding-authorization/

in my oidc config i have set jwk keys, set resource indicators feature to format my access token in jwt format, so thats why i follow that tutorial, i think i have implemented correctly but i still get 401 unathorized

```
resourceIndicators: {
          defaultResource(ctx) {
            return ctx.origin;
          },
          getResourceServerInfo(ctx, resourceIndicator, client) {
            return {
              scope: client.scope as string,
              audience: 'account',
              accessTokenFormat: 'jwt',
            };
          },
          useGrantedResource(ctx, model) {
            return true;
          },
        },
```

and here my strategy:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { passportJwtSecret } from 'jwks-rsa';

import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'jwt') {
  constructor(config: ConfigService) {
    super({
      secretOrKeyProvider: passportJwtSecret({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
        jwksUri: 'http://localhost:3000/oidc/jwks',
        timeout: 300,
      }),
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      audience: 'account',
      issuer: 'http://localhost:3000',
      algorithms: ['RS256'],
    });
  }

  validate(payload: unknown): unknown {
    return payload;
  }
}
```

and this is the result of my decoded access token
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtwbo.png)

is there something i missing?